# Is it possible to use facebook java script sdk in unity to use firebase in amazon?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using firebase unity version in my unity project but i wan't to upload my project in amazon but firebase is not supported in amazon.
I saw at one place that you can use firebase javascript sdk in amazon platform.
is it possible to convert unity firebase sdk to Firebase javascript sdk?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your high level question: unless you find some way to embed a JavaScript engine in your Unity game, this will not work for you. You may be able to export a web project and put it in an electron container, then build your own plugin around the [JavaScript plugin system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) -- but the Firebase games team does not provide C# hooks for the JavaScript SDK and you'd have to ship a web app in a native container.

Since that's probably not going to be your ideal path forward, I have some other suggestions you can try:

1. [fairly difficult/time consuming] The problem with the Firebase Games SDK on Amazon devices is that they don't have Google Play Services. Historically this has been necessary for Firebase on Android, although this is not [universally true anymore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services). Unfortunately, the games SDK has not yet been configured in a way to bypass this restriction (although they are tracking a [related feature request](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/223)). You may instead try to use Unity's new [gradle build system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) and integrate Firebase using Unity's own [JNI binding layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJNI.html). This is the most time intensive solution, but will get you closest to what is offered by the official games SDK.
2. [easy but lacking features/official support] There are a number of plugins on the asset store that work with Firebase (such as [this one](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/simple-firebase-unity-for-realtime-database-58337)). Typically they tend to use the REST apis ([ex for Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)), which also means they work in most (all?) of Unity's target platforms with the drawbacks that they're not officially supported by the Firebase team and might not have some of the client work done that the native SDKs do to improve performance.
3. [impractical but cool] Something I've always been curious about, the C++ SDK (the base of the Firebase Unity SDK) does have desktop linux support and is [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk). I'd be really interested if you're able to run "Linux Desktop" on an Android phone, but I bet that C++'s lack of ABI stability will make it hard/impossible to generate a drop in SDK replacement.

I wish I had a better answer for you, but this is a current weakness of the Firebase Games SDK.